# StatusBarOrientation animation problem on iPad

Tags: iphone

I'm developing app for iPhone that is show other view each orientation(Portrate and Landscape).

and I programed no statusBar animation like this.

> [application setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];

But when I launch app on iPad and rotate it,

statusBar Animation occered!

Why statusBar Animation setting is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to disable the animation, without breaking everything apart.

The following codes will disable the "black box" rotation animation, without messing with other animations or orientation code:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
  /* Your original orientation booleans*/
}
```

Place it in your UIViewController and all should be well. Same method can be applied to any undesired animation in iOS.

Best of luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks a million! your code erased my nightmarish animation bug!!

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the orientation setting to your info.plist file?

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation~ipad</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
```